# vba: powerpoint macro: "variable not set"

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I'm getting a  `"Object variable or With block variable not set"` error in my code.
This is my first crack at macro writing. I do have programming knowledge but this is new to me.

Anyway, I want to go through the presentation, and for every page that has any text in the notes section, I want to add a new slide (following it) containing that text.

Here's what I tried:

```
Sub SlideSort()
Dim curSlide As Slide
Dim newSld As Slide
Dim curPres As Presentation
Dim curShape As Shape
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        curSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

        For Each curShape In curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes
            If curShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                If curShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
                    If curShape.TextFrame.TextRange <> "" Then
                        Set newSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=i + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutText)
                        newSld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = curShape.TextFrame.TextRange
                        i = i + 1

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next curShape
    Next i

End Sub
```

The line that gives the error is curSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Set curSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)` - it's an **object**, and should be operated via `Set`.

Comment: Thanks! Any wiser ways to do what I'm trying to do, out of curiosity?
I guess for macros like this computational efficiency isn't particularly of the essence.

Comment: Perhaps combine nested `If`s using `And`s.

Comment: Also, after correcting the set command, I got a new error: PlaceholderFormat(unknown member): Failed

For this line: If curShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then

Comment: You need to address specific Item in Placeholders collection. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221221%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: (not sure what the protocol is...do I edit my original post to show the new error...or start a new thread?)

Comment: The code, once corrected to "Set curSlide = ..." etc works here. Are you running this from w/in PPT or from some other app

Comment: One other thing to note:  As is, it'll keep adding new slides with the same body text each time you run it.  I'd add a tag to the newly added slide then at the beginning of each run, look for any slides with this tag and delete them prior to adding slides back.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg maybe its b/c I'm running ppt 2011? I'm running the macro from within ppt not in an app

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Set here, as you have with other objects:

```
Set curSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
```

Comment: you overbeaten me for 31 sec))) +1

Answer (score 0):

Bingo.  It's a bug in the Mac version of PowerPoint.  I can repro the problem on the Mac.

.PlaceholderFormat.Type isn't supported on Mac PowerPoint, though it should be.

It's not 100% reliable, but you can pick up the second shape on the notes page as the body text placeholder instead:

```
Sub SlideSort()
Dim curSlide As Slide
Dim newSld As Slide
Dim curPres As Presentation
Dim curShape As Shape
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        curSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
        curShape = curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2)
           If curShape.TextFrame.TextRange <> "" Then
              Set newSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=i + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutText)
              newSld.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = curShape.TextFrame.TextRange
              i = i + 1
           End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I suspect you may also run into issues because you're looking at Slide.Count in the loop, but by adding slides, you're modifying Slide.Count.